# Office365 Emails Sync Failing

Tags: email, office365

I have mirrored my Office 365 web app to my local machine. I have a custom folder created in my mailbox which is connected to one third party application. All the emails that are moved to this custom folder basically gets synced to that application.

But when I try fetching those emails using Office 365 REST APIs (based on the folder ID), I am getting an error response "ErrorItemNotFound".

But I tried with one more Office 365 account which is not mirrored, the emails sync is working perfectly. So is there any difference in pulling the emails if the account is mirrored?

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The specified object was not found in the store."}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario. You said you 'mirrored' your app, but then you say the accounts are 'mirrored'? How did you 'mirror' the accounts?

Comment: I have installed office 365 in my desktop (connected to my online account), when I move a mail from 'inbox' to a custom folder and sync to other app using Office365 REST API getting the above mentioned error as response. Is there any settings that I need to do or REST API will not work in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The IDs change if you move items to other folders. Maybe that's what you're seeing?

Comment: Even though IDs changes it does not matter to me because I am trying to fetch all the mails that are moved to that custom folder. But I am not sure the exact reason for this because it works fine for the account that does not have Office 365 App connected to my local machine. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Post the request you're making. There's not enough information here for me to guess what's going on.